# Create single Installer for all browser extension (Chrome, Firefox,IE,Safari) Using C# --Crossrider

Tags: cross-browser, crossrider

I created browser extensions for chrome(.crx) firefox(.xpi) and IE(.exe) using crossrider, Now what I have to do is I need to create one installation setup(.exe) using C# which will install or add all the extensions to the browsers when we install that single setup. I Prefer to write the code in C#, or if is there any possibility or any other way to achieve this functionality please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

The option to create a multi-browser installer exists within the IDE on the (**Settings** >) **Windows Installer** page. Until recently, this included the option to bundle Chrome as well, however due to recent Chrome policy changes this option has been removed. Instead, for Chrome we recommend using the (**Settings** >) **Export to Chrome Web Store** option to conform with the new Chrome policy.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I gone through it,but it is for IE and Firefox then how can we use this installer for Safari browser.

Comment: The installer is for Windows and since currently Apple only support Safari on Macs, we do not support Safari in the installer.

Comment: @Shlomo I need your help regarding building my project in crossrider. Please help me out.